# WAS serialization exception from un-used package

Tags: java, logging, serialization, websphere

I am seeing the following exception in my production WebSphere 8 server log:

```
WASSession    E MTMBuffWrapper getBytes write object exception. 
e= java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger
```

However the only logging package used in deployed application is `java.util.logging.Logger`.

I am not seeing any serialization exception in my local RAD server, only in production environment.

Any idea?

Comment: @DaniEll posted (as an answer, because he currently does not have the rep to comment) "please post the stacktrace - we need to see what's getting serialized / started serialization.."

Comment: The OP responded with "This is the only line for this exception, when/if I see an exception from my application code then I see the full stack trace but for this exception thrown directly from the WAS server using its own code to serialize session objects then it only outputs this line to the SystemOut.log nothing in SystemErr.log either. "

Answer (score 0):

You don't see exceptions in RAD because you dont have persistence session enabled or PMI counter collecting the session size (which is probably set on the production).

Although you don't use `org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger` in your code there is very high probability that some kind of third party framework that you use in your app is using it.

You have to check what objects you put in the session (search for all `session.setAttribute()` method calls). You must be putting some third party object into session which is using that logger.

Try to remove commons-logging-1.1.jar from your application, if you have one there.

Comment: So presumably I can enable the same in my local server and be able to get to the offending class, or would it also spit out a one liner. I made sure all session object implemented Serializable and had a NoArg constructor.

Comment: @TDupard Yes, you can enable PMI via admin console. Either select `All` or go to `Custom` and in the `Servlet Session Manager` module enable `SessionObjectSize`.

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere internally uses the commons-logging library, so the conflict rises.  We faced a similar problem, also using IBM provided solutions like https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/javaionotserializableexception-thrown-websphere-application-server-community-edition-when-applications-are-stopped did not help. In our case use, the jcl-over-slf4j library solved the problem.